# Why do I get a FileNotFoundExpection when running a function in lein repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Using this Clojure [project.clj](https://github.com/ndroock1/bota-web/blob/master/project.clj) I started a REPL in a Windows cmd using

```
lein figwheel
```

I ran the following macro

```
(ns bota-web.views
    (:require [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
              [re-com.core :as re-com]))
```

with nil as result. I expected this result.

Then I started a REPL in a Windows cmd using

```
lein repl
```

I ran the same macro and see below what happened.

```
D:\Dropbox\DATA\MyClojureProjects\bota-web>lein repl
nREPL server started on port 59329 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:59329
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.8.0_45-b15
Docs: (doc function-name-here)
      (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
Source: (source function-name-here)
Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (ns bota-web.views
  #_=>     (:require [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
  #_=>               [re-com.core :as re-com]))

FileNotFoundException Could not locate re_frame/core__init.class or re_frame/core.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:456)
user=>
```

Given the [project.clj](https://github.com/ndroock1/bota-web/blob/master/project.clj) can it be determined why I received the FileNotFoundException this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `lein figwheel` you start a **ClojureScript** REPL so you can `require` CLJS namespaces (e.g. `re-frame.core`).

When you use `lein repl` you start a **Clojure** REPL which works only with Clojure namespaces and thus the error: Clojure tries to find Clojure namespace named `re-frame.core` but it fails.

Comment: Now I understand why I have to do this https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-in-a-Cursive-Clojure-REPL to get a REPL working in IntelliJ because that's my real problem.

Comment: And that worked too, I now have Cursive, the Clojure plugin for IntelliJ working. Coding outside my familiar IDE does not feel right. ;-)

Comment: I'm glad to hear I was helpful.